# Get the number of users subscribed to a pusher channel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, channel, pusher

I'm implementing an application using vue.js and Pusher (for realtime multi-user communication). The application provide that each user authenticate himself (accessing the home page) and ,before starting, he sets some settings in the home page (about his role in the application). The subscription to the pusher shared channel takes place when accessing the home page component. I need each user to be unable to select anything in the home page until all the other users subscribe to the channel (accessing the home page), that is the settings section in the home page has to be enabled for all the users only if everyone is subscribed to the channel. I'm a begginner with Pusher and in the pusher documentation I found that there is a way to get the number of the user subscribed to the channel(on which to perform a control to achive my purpose) using the property "subscription_count" after enabling this possibility in the "App settings" section of the pusher dashboard.
In particular this is what I found: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/library_auth_reference/rest-api (in the "GET channel (fetch info for one channel)" paragraph). However, I don't understard if I can get the subscription preperty directly through the channel instance with this syntax: *pusher.info.subscription_count*, where "pusher" is:

```
 const pusher = new Pusher('********', {
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true,
    authEndpoint: 'https://*****/pusher/auth'
  })
```

or if I have to use another syntax.
Moreover, I want to know if this property updates dinamically in order to enable the setting section (for example using a v-if condition based on the subscriptions number) only if the count is equal to a specific value. I hope that you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already authenticating users I would recommend using [presence channels](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels).

You subscribe to a presence channel on the client by subscribing to a channel with the presence- prefix.

There are a few features of presence channels that should help meet your requirements:

1) When a client subscribes to a presence channel they will be assigned a userid in the [authentication response](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users#implementing-the-auth-endpoint-for-a-presence-channel) (so you can keep track of exactly "who" has subscribed). Unlike subscription counts multiple subscriptions from the same user wont be counted twice

2) When a client subscribes to a presence channel, along with the subscription succeeded event they will get a [members](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels#pusher-subscription-succeeded) object returned which contains a list of all the members already present in the channel. This means from the client you can accurately get the existing count of users.

3) You can bind [member_added](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels#pusher-member-added) and member_removed events. This will trigger a callback each time a someone joins or leaves the channel. Each time a member is added to a channel you can update a count until it reaches the required number